Change Order of Tags using Swagger in C#
I´m currently changing our ASP.NET API to the OpenAPI format and thus I use Swagger to generate the API File automatically.
There seems to be no way of defining the Order of these Tags globally. Additionally I would like to add descriptions to each tag.
Any Ideas?
I´ve already found out that I can add Tags to Controllers and Methods using the [Tags] Attribute, and I know, that I can add tag descriptions and stuff directly in the generated yaml, but I would like completely create the yaml using swagger in ASP.NET.
My code looks like this:
Program.cs
services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.EnableAnnotations();
    c.OperationFilter<TagOrderFilter>();
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "InboundApp",
        Version = "v1",
        Description = "bla",
    });
    
});

Controller:
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
[Tags("Finishing the import")]
[HttpPatch("{id}", Name = nameof(ImportProcessController) +`"." + nameof(PatchImportProcess))]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchImportProcess(string id, [FromBody] PatchDto patchDto)
{ ...

I do have about 6-7 Tags and multiple Tags at some controllers

Concrete example would be useful - what you get and why it is not what you want, a.k.a. Minimal, Reproducible Example

You could try create Empty Tags with your order before endpoints use them.
    public class EmptyTagsDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            // Add empty tags to the Swagger document
            swaggerDoc.Tags.Add(new OpenApiTag { Name = "Tag3" });
            swaggerDoc.Tags.Add(new OpenApiTag { Name = "Tag2" });
            swaggerDoc.Tags.Add(new OpenApiTag { Name = "Tag1" });
        }
    }

Then in program.cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.EnableAnnotations();
    c.DocumentFilter<EmptyTagsDocumentFilter>();
};

Test result


Tried that, but it doesn´t work. I debugged and found out, that the filter only gets one tag at a time, so it can´t sort anything

@Jonizn Sorry for that. You are right. I found another way and update the answer.
